# BeautifulSoup can't find the string from .select_one

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

With `.select_one` I get this html, but `.string` doesn't see the text inside:

```
In: project.select_one('div.block-i:has(> i.fal.fa-thumbs-up)')
Out: <div class="block-i"><i class="fal fa-thumbs-up"></i>33 072<span>votes</span></div>

In: project.select_one('div.block-i:has(> i.fal.fa-thumbs-up)').string
Out: None
```

There is no such problem with `selectolax`:

```
In: project.css_first('div.block-i:has(> i.fal.fa-thumbs-up)').html
Out: <div class="block-i"><i class="fal fa-thumbs-up"></i>33 096<span>votes</span></div>

In: project.css_first('div.block-i:has(> i.fal.fa-thumbs-up)').text()
Out: 33 096votes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `text` method it will work `string` does not work if it has multiple tags in it

```
soup=BeautifulSoup("<div class='block-i'><i class='fal fa-thumbs-up'></i>33 072<span>votes</span></div>")
print(soup.select_one('div.block-i:has(>i.fal.fa-thumbs-up)').text)
```

Output:

```
33 072votes
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) (emphasis mine):

> If a tag has only **one** child, and that child is a `NavigableString`, the child is made available as `.string`.
>
> ...
> If a tag contains **more than one thing**, then it’s not clear what
> `.string` should refer to, so `.string` is defined to be **`None`**.

Instead, you can use the [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method, which will return the HTML text as a single Unicode string:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """<div class="block-i"><i class="fal fa-thumbs-up"></i>33 072<span>votes</span></div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.select_one("div.block-i:has(> i.fal.fa-thumbs-up)").get_text(separator=" "))
```

Output:

```
33 072 votes
```